# Why do sp2 carbons tend to prefer eclipsed conformations whereas sp3 carbons prefer staggered

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

I am a second year undergraduate and have come across this when studying stereochemistry and conformations and have been unable to find a satisfactory answer.

I know that $\ce{sp^3}$ carbons prefer anti-periplanar and gauche conformations due to the overlap of filled orbitals with empty orbitals but cannot seem to find an answer for why $\ce{sp^2}$ carbons prefer an eclipsed conformation. I was possibly thinking about the need to avoid $\pi$ electrons however I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are asking about preferred conformations for $\ce{sp^3-sp^3}$ single bonds and $\ce{sp^3-sp^2}$ single bonds.

You are correct that the staggered (or gauche) conformation is preferred in simple alkanes.  This is generally explained by noting that

- adverse steric interactions are minimized in the staggered conformation, and
- stabilizing [hyperconjugative interactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconjugation) are maximized

[image]
([From: “Isomers of Organic Compounds”, section 24.2 from the book Principles of General Chemistry (v. 1.0).](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/principles-of-general-chemistry-v1.0/s28-02-isomers-of-organic-compounds.html))

In the case of the $\ce{sp^3-sp^2}$ single bond as found in propene, toluene, acetaldehyde, etc., the eclipsed conformation is now the more stable.

[image]
([Michael Di Maso, Jared Shaw, the UC Davis ChemWiki by University of California](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Wikitexts/UC_Davis/UCD_Chem_231A%3A_Methods_of_Organic_Synthesis/Content/Conformational_Analysis/Acyclic_Conformations))

Again both steric and electronic arguments can be advanced to explain this preference.  The steric argument says let's use the bent model to describe the double bond.

[image]

Now replace one of those ethylene hydrogens with a methyl group and note that in the eclipsed conformation (build a model if you can) none of the methyl hydrogens eclipse the hydrogen on the adjacent olefinic carbon or any of the bent bonds.  In the staggered conformation all 3 of the methyl hydrogens are eclipsing something, the 2 bent bonds and the $\ce{C-H}$ bond on the adjacent olefinic carbon.  The basis of the electronic argument can be found [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Wikitexts/UC_Davis/UCD_Chem_231A%3A_Methods_of_Organic_Synthesis/Content/Conformational_Analysis/Acyclic_Conformations).  Personally, for me, the steric argument is easier to understand.